# Why is ostream::operator<< a global function for char parameters?

Tags: c++, iostream, global, ostream

Acording to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/ the operator<< method defined on e.g. streambuf is a member of ostream, but for char / char * it is a global function. What's the design decision behind this difference?

Comment: Not sure I understand - the operator is defined on ostream not streambuf, from that article. Also e.g. ostream& operator<< (bool& val ); is a member of ostream (despite not being a class, like char); I'm just trying to understand the difference here.

Comment: Ah I see where you're coming from I think, you're saying that all the primitive types should have global functions, all the objects should have the ostream::operator<< defined as part of the object.

Comment: I must apologise, my comment was completely wrong...  As you point out, the `operator<<()` does/would belong to `ostream` regardless of the type of the element being operated on.  (I'll blame low caffeine levels...)  I've now deleted this misleading comment.  Also: good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator<<` for `streambuf*` (or `int` which sounds a simpler case) and `char` could have been both implemented as member operators, or as non-member (free) operators.

My guess is that it's due to retro-compatibility issues emerged while C++ was being defined: maybe older code was relaying on a member `operator<<(int)`, and thus they decided not to move it as a free operator.

The C++ standard library (and also STL) have a number of dishomogeneity like this one.

Comment: So long as there's not a deeper reason I'm missing I'm happy with this answer, thanks.